# Simultaneous downloading a file and inserting to mysql database with python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, multiprocessing, urllib2

I'm downloading relatively large files (10mb each) with urllib2, and then loading it as a json file and inserting data into a mysql database, and then repeating the process in an infinite loop.  The downloading takes a minute or so, and then it loads everything into mysql.  Is there a way to create a thread that does the downloading while the main thread inserts into mysql using python?

my pseudocode:

```
while 1:
 download file with urllib2
 decode as json file
 extract data I want
 do some computations on data
 insert data into mysql
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Twisted. Twisted is always the answer.

Comment: Twisted (as said by Ignacio) or Tornado, they are both Asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use threads and queues. A file IO thread would read and process the file and then insert the result into a queue, where a database IO thread would then discover the result and do the work. Rather than code up an example, I'll direct you here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Alternately you could use the python `select` module to manage multiple file read operations and handle them one by one as they complete: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html

Comment: Maybe multiprocessing (or process pool) colud be safer.

Comment: A good point in the case where multiple processors would be useful: a CPU bound operation. In an IO bound situation the extra processors aren't the worry - getting the IO not to block is.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for.  So I just have to modify the "run" function in the given example with my own code?

Comment: Right -- the python thread's `start` method hands off to the `run` method where you define the work that the thread will do. So you would likely have one thread class whose `run` method downloads and processes the files, another thread class whose `run` method does database inserts. And as the example demonstrates it is easy to set up a thread pool so you could be downloading/inserting multiple files at the same time.